# wp_audio_shortcode shows player and url

Tags: audio

When I use my code below inside the WP loop I get to see both the player and the url. Needless to say, I only want to see the player.

How to correct my code so it'll only show the player?

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
$fes_featured_audio = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'upload_featured_audio', true ); // custom upload field

if (is_array($fes_featured_audio)) {    
    foreach($fes_featured_audio as $key=>$val){ 

        if ( $key < 1) {
            $url_audio = wp_get_attachment_url( $val ); 
        } else {
            $url_audio_playlist   = explode(',', get_attached_media( 'audio', $val ) ); 
        }

    }
}


$attr = array(
    'src'      => strip_tags($url_audio),
    'loop'     => 'true',
    'autoplay' => '',
    'preload'  => 'auto',
);

if ( $key < 1) {
    echo '<div class="audio-player" itemprop="audio">' . wp_audio_shortcode( $attr ) . ' </div>';
} else {
    echo do_shortcode('[playlist ids="'.$url_audio_playlist.'"]');
}
```

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/media.php#L2173 and https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1864 both seem to return html. Can you narrow it down to which line produces extra output?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know which line is line is adding the extra output. :(

Comment: It's super easy, you should comment out lines from the bottom up until the output stops. That's how you find out what is causing it. Then you narrow in on that specific line.

Comment: `<div class="audio-player" itemprop="audio">' . wp_audio_shortcode( $attr ) . ' </div>` outputs both the player and extra url. If I remove this line, both are gone.  I think I'm close to finding the cause actually. I used `strip_tags($url_audio)` but the extra html link code that is automatically added because it's an url, doesn't get stripped. I also tried `html_entity_decode` but that didn't work either. Do you perhaps have any other ideas?

Comment: Try `'src' => esc_attr( esc_url( strip_tags( $url_audio ) ) ),`

Comment: or replace your `$url_audio = 'http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Canon.mp3';` to see if it has anything to do with the link specifically. I tested this locally and I'm not seeing extra link info.

Comment: I tried both options and oddly, the url was still there. Then it suddenly hit me; there was nothing wrong with the function I wrote, but the function was placed inside an url `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">my-function</a>` in a page template. ^^;;;

Comment: Nice! Consider adding that as an answer to your question to mark this question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the function above. Turns out my function was placed inside an *a href* tag.